# How can i create a lookup in Django?

Tags: python, django, lookup

I have a Question model & Form, one of the fields in this model is **userid=ForeignKey(User)**, this Works perfectly well on the Question Model, am able to pick the user from a drop down.

But kind a tricky when i want to list the question from the model, which is the best way to **lookup** the user name from the Users table? becouse at this point i cant have the dropdown!

I want to have a simple thing e.g.

Question Title
asked by:**lookup user Name**

Answer (score 5):

The name of your field (`userid` instead of `user`) makes me think that you may be confused about the behavior of Django's `ForeignKey`.

If you define a model like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

And then instantiate a `Question` as `question`:

```
>>> question.user # the `User` instance
<User: username>

>>> question.user_id # the user's primary key
1
```

It looks like you may be expecting `question.userid` to be the user's primary key, rather than what it actually is: the `User` instance itself.  When you access `question.userid`, a database lookup is performed, but it's done automatically by Django using the value of `question.userid_id`.  I would rename the `userid` field to `user` to avoid confusion.

With that out of the way, I think what you are trying to do is list the questions along with their associated users.  If that's the case, do something like this in your template:

```
<ol>
{% for question in questions %}
    <li>{{ question }} asked by: {{ question.user }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find your question vague. If you want to fetch all `Question` instances that are related to a particular `User` instance given a `user_name`, you can do thus:

```
questions = Question.objects.filter( userid__username='user_name' )
```

If you already have a `User` instance (held, say, in a variable called `user`) and would like to fetch all `Question` objects related to it, you can get those with:

```
questions = user.question_set.all()
```